The `handleChange` function does not change anything
I need to add objects to an array using useState, but it won't update
const [chosenPro, setChosenPro] = useState([])


const handleCheck = (e, item, max) => {
    const isChecked = e.target.checked

    //this log runs properly and shows the correct input in the console
    //{index: 'skill-arcana', name: 'Skill: Arcana', url: '/api/proficiencies/skill-arcana'}
    console.log(item)
    if(isChecked && chosenPro.length === 0){
        setChosenPro([item])
        
        //this log shows an empty array
        console.log('number 1', chosenPro)
    }
    else if(isChecked && chosenPro.length >= 1) {
        //this log wont show up, because the array is always empty
        setChosenPro((prevPro) => [...prevPro, item])
        console.log('number 2', chosenPro)
    }else if(!isChecked){
        
        setChosenPro((prevPro) => prevPro.filter((pro) => pro !== item))
        //this log show an empty array when I uncheck a box
        console.log('number 3', chosenPro)
    }
}

I tried adding logic to account for the array being empty and I was expecting the object to be logged like this
const chosenPro = [
  {
    index: "skill-arcana",
    name: "Skill: Arcana",
    url: "/api/proficiencies/skill-arcana",
  },
  {
    index: "skill-animal-handling",
    name: "Skill: Animal Handling",
    url: "/api/proficiencies/skill-animal-handling",
  },
];


i tried replacing useState with .push and that mostly works, but ive heard youre not supposed to do that with react as it can cause problems

This sounds like the closure your handleCheck function is running in has reference to previously created version of chosenPro, without more of your code it's hard to say.
An easy fix for this would be to move more of your logic into the setState function and utilise the provided parameter for your checks:
const handleCheck = (e, item, max) => {
    const isChecked = e.target.checked

    setChosenPro(currentPro => {
        console.log(item)

        if(isChecked && currentPro.length === 0) {
            const newValue = [item]
            console.log('number 1', newValue)

            // set chosenPro to new Array with single new item.
            return newValue;
        }

        if(isChecked && currentPro.length >= 1) {
            const newValue = [...currentPro, item]

            console.log('number 2', newValue)

            // set chosenPro to new Array with existing items + new item.
            return newValue;
        }
        
        if(!isChecked){
            const newValue =  currentPro.filter((pro) => pro !== item);

            console.log('number 3', newValue)

            // set chosenPro to new Array with existing items - selected item.
            return newValue;
        }

        // do not change chosenPro
        return currentPro;
    })

}


that sorta worked. i checked, and theres no refernece to setCurrentPro anywhere else in my code except this function and i havent used currentPro to change the state with some other method either. with this code it only runs the first if statement, but it seems to save the correct data to newValue but when i run a console.log after the final return statement outside the if else block it dosent show a log at all

The state isn't updated until the next render of the component, which react will trigger after your current event handler has completed (if synchronous)

even after multiple events (checking multiple boxes) it only runs the first if. it will save the input to chosenPro but overwrite it on the next event

after just now clicking 3 checkboxes(only one showed up in the log at a time) when i unchecked a box it properly logged the other selected inputs. so i guess its just a rendering problem?

You might need to post more code, I'm unsure what your end goal is so I'm unsure how to progress. Looking at what you have provided I'm lead to assume you have a static list of proficiences that a user can select from and you wish to show the chosen list of proficiences. Here is a rough example of what I think you are working towards: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-xw1dyx?file=src%2FApp.jsx&terminal=dev

so, i tried that and i think it worked. i dont need to display it, im just adding the data to an object to be displayed later. whats weird, is that the only time it shows something other than an empty array for chosenPro is when i run it through a useEffect with chosenPro as a dependency. even when there are multiple items in the array the if else will only show an empty array. i guess thats not a breaking problem i i can still get the data, but its kinda weird, even with async functionality
